# Given the value of $\log n$, what is the value of $\log 2n$?

Tags: logarithms

I had the attached multiple choice question in an online practice exam. I'm not sure how to work this out.

[image: Log Question]

Comment: Is there anything on the exam to indicate that the logarithm is base $2$?

Comment: It's a Computer Science Algorithm and Data Structure class so I would assume it's base 2

Answer (score 5):

Use the property of the logs that says that $\log ab = \log a + \log b$. You get $\log 2n = \log 2 + \log n = 36.5 + \log 2$